# Why is vsts agent on macOS writing /tmp/clr-debug-pipe*[in|out] files every minute?

Tags: .net, node.js, macos, azure-devops

I noticed today that my /tmp folder on my mac (mac mini 2014/macos High Sierra) was full of thousands and thousands of clr-debug-pipe*[in|out] files...

> prwx------  1 dev  wheel  0 28 Okt 17:37 /tmp/clr-debug-pipe-4787-1509205076-in
>   prwx------  1 dev  wheel  0 28 Okt 17:37 /tmp/clr-debug-pipe-4787-1509205076-out

I figured out that they are related to the vsts agent (Agent Version from August 2017) I had started as an service (svc.sh start) and forgot to stop.

> ps -edf
>   501   547   506   0  8Okt17 ??         5:54.94 ./externals/node/bin/node ./bin/AgentService.js

After stoping the agent the writing of files stopped immediately. Starting it again it wrote again every minute some clr-debug-pipe*[in|out] files.

Is there a way to stop writing these files? And where to configure? Didn't find it in the documents!?

Why are they needed?

Comment: What's the result if you setup a new agent? (Download the newest agent and configure it)

Comment: Used vsts-agent-osx.10.11-x64-2.123.0.tar.gz -> 
./config.sh: line 29: 71247 Segmentation fault: 11  ./bin/Agent.Listener configure "$@"

Steps
- revoked old token
- created new token
- deleted the old pool
- deleted the old agent
- downloaded the new tarball
- extracted tarball to new folder '~/bin/agent'
- executed ./config.sh in new folder '~/bin/agent'

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue at my side. And clr-debug-pipe file is usually generated when build with coreclr, did you build this with the agent?

Comment: Well, first, no I did not build with coreclr, since I do a python project with vsts and my macos agent. Also the clr-debug files are even created with no builds running. So it is a (global?) setting influencing the macos vsts agent.

Second I installed the old agent, again. And it produced a segmentation fault 11, also. So I assume that there is a general problem on my mac, now. A re-install of VSfMac and of the mono framework didn't fix the (sf11) problem. So I gave up and switched to a docker run vsts agent. At least this is now a Microsoft maintained environment, so it works reliable...